# How to retrieve ObjectID after PFUser login?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, objectid, pfuser

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(fullName.text, password: password.text) {
(user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

     if user != nil {

       self.loginButton.enabled = false
       self.helpButton.enabled = false

       self.objectID = self.PFUser.objectId
    }
}
```

I need to the users objectID after they log in. I know how to retrieve the objectID for just a PFObject when when it comes to PFUser I get an error (on the last line of code above). How can I get the id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `self.PFUser.objectId`, but I think you mean the `user` that you get back from the completion block. So try:

```
self.objectID = user.objectId
```

in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

You should use either `user.objectId` or `PFUser.currentUser().objectId` instead of `self.PFUser.objectId`:

```
self.objectID = user.objectId
self.objectID = PFUser.currentUser().objectId
```